# WooCommerce page checkout page doesnt work properly in safari browser?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

The final checkout page [Please click here](http://www.noushasasart.com/product/neon-waterfall-council-house-print/) doesn't work properly only on safari browser.
Please Help

[image: this grey section the ORDER SUMMARY]

Comment: In which section you got the error, Please give me more details about it?

Comment: This is after filling all the form details on final check out page. [link](http://www.noushasasart.com/checkout/)

you can demonstrate the page only by adding a product to cart.

Comment: Please check my answer and replay your feedback.

Comment: hi @PPL I didn't find the following CSS code in my style.css or CSS customizing feature

Answer (score 0):

Remove below CSS properties from CSS file.

```
input[type="hidden" i], input[type="image" i], input[type="file" i] {
    -webkit-appearance: initial;
}

input {
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
}
```

Hope this works for you.